# Issue with JetBrains Rider ASP project: Project not opening and files continuously listing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a project developed in Visual Studio, and it works fine. However, when I attempt to open the same project in JetBrains Rider, I encounter a problem. The Rider IDE keeps listing the files in the project continuously, preventing me from accessing the project properly.

I have tried to add , [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgW2H.png)